# Bluetooth Low Energy device doesn't show up in the same phone but it does show up in the different phone while playing music in the same BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

[Android/BLE/Bluetooth]

When I try to connect with the BLE device from the app and then connect to the bluetooth classic with the same device, and play music from the device speakers. App stays connected to it. But when music is still playing and I close & open the app again, BLE doesn't get connected. Also it's not shown in the LightBlue app from the same phone but it's BLE is available to connect from the different phone inside the app and even in LightBlue.

In some phones S10, S8, S9. This error is being produced.
But in Sasmung s21, vivo y33t, it's not happening or occuring.

P.S we are disconnecting the BLE when app gets destroyed/closes that's how it get's available for every other device.

And I've no clue what's blocking it up on the same phone.

I've tried so far to close the connection on onDestroy() method. It didn't even help.